# How to set TextBox cursor position without SelectionStart

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a Windows Forms textbox with background thread updating its value every second.
If I place cursor inside textbox it will loose its current position at next update. Same thing with text selection.

I tried to solve it like that

```
    protected void SetTextProgrammatically(string value)
    {
        // save current cursor position and selection
        int start = textBox.SelectionStart;
        int length = textBox.SelectionLength;

        // update text
        textBox.Text = value;

        // restore cursor position and selection
        textBox.SelectionStart = start;
        textBox.SelectionLength = length;
    }
```

It works good most of the time. Here is situation when it does not work:
 
1) I place cursor at the end of the text in textbox
2) press SHIFT and move cursor to the left using <- arrow key
Selection won't work properly.

It looks like combination `SelectionStart=10` and `SelectionLength=1` automatically moves cursor to position 11 (not 10 as I want it to be).

Please let me know if there is anything I can do about it! I am using Framework.NET 2.0.
There must be a way to set cursor position in textbox other then `SelectionStart+SelectionLength`.

Comment: What excatly does *it will loose its current position at next update* mean? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It means that cursor will jump to the beginning of the text

Comment: I want this textbox to work just any other textbox. The way it works now is sometimes irritating. I mean I can select text inside this textbox only moving from left to right. And I just cannot do it moving from right to left

Comment: I think that the behavior you see IS the normal behavior. The cursor is always on the end of the selection, and using a arrow key causes the selection length to be 0.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I agree with you. But in ordinary textbox you can select text moving from right to left, right? The only difference of my textbox is that it's text is changing in background while i'm trying to work with it.

Comment: I mean there must be a way to improve my current code. I tried to use GetCaretPos/SetCaretPos but without success. Maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: Is this occurs when you select english text? or only when selecting right-to-left language text?

Comment: Done :) But what do I do now?

Comment: It's english (number of digits actually)

Comment: What code is executed on mouse move? I understand that you do something there with `GetCaretPos` and you expect cursor position to be on `SelectionStart`. Avoid using WinApi functions for this, use `TextBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(TextBox.SelectionStart)` instead. This may not be correct for right to left languages.

Comment: No Mouse events involved. I tried to use `GetCaretPos/SetCaretPos` functions to improve current behaviour but it did not work so I removed it. I don't understand how `GetPositionFromCharIndex` will help me.

Comment: Ok, i thought so. It's not relevant anymore. By the way, it's not bidirectional issue, so you should re-edit back... sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution!

```
        // save current cursor position and selection 
        int start = textBox.SelectionStart;
        int length = textBox.SelectionLength;

        Point point = new Point();
        User32.GetCaretPos(out point);

        // update text
        textBox.Text = value;

        // restore cursor position and selection
        textBox.Select(start, length);
        User32.SetCaretPos(point.X, point.Y);
```

Now its working just like it should.

Answer (score 4):

```
//save position
            bool focused = textBox1.Focused;
            int start = textBox1.SelectionStart;
            int len = textBox1.SelectionLength;
            //do your work
            textBox1.Text = "duviubobioub";
            //restore
            textBox1.SelectionStart = start;
            textBox1.SelectionLength = len ;
            textBox1.Select();
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between your suggestion and code that I'm already using.

Comment: Sorry.. I forgot the Select()

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the solution - nothing changed. I still cannot select text inside textbox moving cursor from right to left.

Comment: I posted the whole code I used to test the feature and it works for me, including right to left selection

Comment: It is strange, suggested code shouldn't be working (just as mine). And it still does not work for me. Function Select(start, length) places cursor at the end of selection (you can actually see it). Problem occurs only when you're moving from right to left because in this case you're moving in opposite directions.

Comment: What I think will solve the problem is something like: textBox1.CaretIndex = start; added to the end of my function.

Comment: Or some function Select(startIndex, endIndex) which will place cursor to endIndex position (even if endIndex < startIndex)

Answer (score 1):

To set the cursor position in textbox without selection start...!

```
textbox1.Select(textbox1.text.length,0); /* ===> End of the textbox  */
  textbox1.Select(0,0);                    /* ===> Start of the textbox  */
```

Comment: When i use the Select(0,0);  it starts at 1, leaving a space behind. My mask is "000-000-0000"