# Windows Forms Textbox: Selection and Caret position

Tags: c#, windows, forms, textbox

After setting the SelectionStart and SelectionLength, the Caret is at the end of the selection.

How can I move the Caret to the beginning of the selection?

---

I now tried this:   The question is not answered by the other threads

```
SelectionStart = selStart;  // set the desired position
SelectionLength = 0;
MyLibs.WindowsDll.POINT point;
MyLibs.WindowsDll.GetCaretPos(out point); // save the position
SelectionLength = restOfWord.Length;      // extend the selection
MyLibs.WindowsDll.SetCaretPos(point.X, point.Y);  // restore caret position
```

GetCaretPos and SetCaretPos are working somehow, but not as it should.
Using the above code snippet, the caret is indeed blinking at the beginning of the selection.

But ... then I hit backspace or cursor left/right, the caret still behaves like it is still at the end of the selection.

Comment: Don't think it's possible with only managed code. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104320/textbox-selectionstart-selectionend-and-caret-cursor-position) similar question.

Comment: You may also check the link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138165/how-to-set-textbox-cursor-position-without-selectionstart)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can not do this using managed code like C#, 
but to achieve this goal you may use C++, `SetFocus()` function,
for example:

```
//use SetFocus()
pEdit->SetFocus()
//place caret at the end:
pEdit->SendMessage (WM_KEYDOWN,VK_END,0);
//simulate keyup:
m_Edit->SendMessage (WM_KEYUP,VK_END,0);
//send the key code:
m_Edit->SendMessage(WM_CHAR,'A',0);
```

Have a look to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646312(v=vs.85).aspx

You may use also `CEdit::SetSel` to accomplish that:

```
CEdit* e = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
e->SetFocus();
e->SetSel(0,-1); // move cursor at the end
e->SetSel(-1); // remove selection
```

See details in Stackoverflow question: [CEdit control MFC, placing cursor to end of string after SetWindowText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480873/cedit-control-mfc-placing-cursor-to-end-of-string-after-setwindowtext)

UPDATED:

If you need to set position to the beginning you can reset the Caret position to start before displaying the text using:

```
SetSel (0,0);
```

You can not move the caret to the beginning while keeping the text selected using basic C#/C++ functions, however you can override basic "Caret" logic using C++ or/and Assembler.

Comment: The problem is not to set the caret/cursor to the end of the text, but to the beginning of the selection. (Caret on the left side of the selected area)

Comment: With SetSel(0,0) the cursor is at the beginning of the edit control. But what I want is eg select characters 4 to 10 and have the caret before the 4th character and not after the 10th.